# Save isolated storage file in Microsoft Office in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

i am creating file in isolated storage area in my application. in any email application on windows phone , for example Gmail Email App, when we download any document from email it by default saves in "Microsoft Office" App , same way i want to save isolated storage file to Microsoft Office App.. Please Help..

Answer (score 2):

I think its not possible as there is no way access to other app's isolated storage. But you can save the images and musics to gallery by using "Medialibrary" class. There is no api provided by office app to store documents in by other apps.